# Why can't i delete my todo item using filter?

Tags: reactjs, filter

I'm trying to make the function to delete my todo item but when click on the delete button, nothing happens, is there anything wrong with my codes, plsease help me! Thank you so much!

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);

  // you can use the submit itself, no need for an extra addTodo function
  handleSubmit = (e) => {
    console.log("x");
    e.preventDefault();
    setTodos([...todos, value]);
    setValue("");
  };

  deleteTodo = (id) => {
    console.log("delete")
    const removedArr = [...todos].filter(todo => todo.id !== id);

    setTodos(removedArr);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input
          onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)}
          type="text"
          placeholder="add todo"
        />
        <button type="submit">Add</button>
      </form>
      {todos.map((todoValue) => (
        <div>
        {todoValue} <button deleteTodo={()=>deleteTodo(id)}>x</button>
        </div>

      ))}
      
  </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

Link codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-cdn-cy3w4?file=/src/App.js:0-933

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70547151/dynamically-delete-elements/70547226#70547226

Comment: what is id ?is there any id that blongs to each todovalue?

Comment: your todos are just strings, they don't have any ids

Comment: you need to add `id` to your todos, like this:  https://codesandbox.io/s/dry-moon-5c3jc?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 3):

see this code

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);

  // you can use the submit itself, no need for an extra addTodo function
  handleSubmit = (e) => {
    console.log("x");
    e.preventDefault();
    setTodos([...todos, value]);
    setValue("");
  };
  deleteTodo = (id) => {
    console.log("delete");
    console.log(id);
    const removedArr = [...todos].filter((todo) => todo !== id);

    setTodos(removedArr);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <input
        onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)}
        type="text"
        placeholder="add todo"
      />
      <button type="submit" onClick={handleSubmit}>
        Add
      </button>

      {todos.map((todoValue) => (
        <div>
          {todoValue} <button onClick={() => deleteTodo(todoValue)}>x</button>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

**Work Demo**

https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-estrela-k5xvu?file=/src/App.js:0-932

Answer (score 3):

There is two mistakes in your code :

1. button should call the deleteTodo function when user clicks on that button i.e onClick() function
2. id is undefined.
   Please refer to this sandbox code example.
   I corrected your code and now it is working .[Link to sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-snow-oz2ew?file=/src/App.js)

Following the code written inside sandbox.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);

  // you can use the submit itself, no need for an extra addTodo function
  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    console.log("x");
    e.preventDefault();
    setTodos([...todos, value]);
    setValue("");
  };

  const deleteTodo = (index) => {
    console.log("delete");
    const removedArr = [...todos].filter((todo, i) => index !== i);

    setTodos(removedArr);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input
          onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)}
          type="text"
          placeholder="add todo"
        />
        <button type="submit">Add</button>
      </form>
      {todos.map((todoValue, index) => (
        <div>
          {todoValue} <button onClick={() => deleteTodo(index)}>x</button>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

Answer (score 3):

you should use onClick in button and your list does not have id so use **todo** instead of **todo.id**:

```
      deleteTodo = (id) => {
     const removedArr = [...todos].filter(todo => todo !== id);
        setTodos(removedArr);
      }
    
      return (
        <div>
          <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <input
              onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)}
              type="text"
              placeholder="add todo"
            />
            <button type="submit">Add</button>
          </form>
          {todos.map((todoValue) => (
            <div>
            {todoValue} <button onClick={()=>deleteTodo(todoValue)}>x</button>
            </div>
    
          ))}
        </div>
      );
    }
    export default App;
```